# Trying to move vertex coords from one UV to another based on 3d Object space nearest vert

Tags: python, blender

I have a Mesh in blender(3.6) which is a human. A have a second mesh in blender which is clothing. Both shares have the same shape as in the clothes are fitted to the human mesh. But the geometry and vertex count and topology are different and dont match. What I need to do is make it so that the clothes conform there uv to the human uv on a per Vertex bases. It doesn’t matter how messy the Vertex’s (on the UV) get for the clothes as in the use case it doesn’t matter.

Basically the issues is that it seems to be doing moving the UVs but in a un predicted way.

Example I expect something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pY8I.jpg)

But get something outputted like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ7DG.png)

This is the before picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9ALr.png)

```
import bpy
import mathutils

def find_nearest_vertex(source_mesh, target_mesh, sphere_radius):
    # Get the vertices from the source mesh
    source_verts = source_mesh.data.vertices
    
    # Dictionary to store the nearest vertex index on target for each source vertex
    nearest_verts = {}
    
    # Iterate through each vertex in the source mesh
    for source_vert_index, source_vert in enumerate(source_verts):
        source_location = source_mesh.matrix_world @ source_vert.co
        
        # Initialize variables for tracking the nearest vertex
        nearest_vert_index = None
        min_distance = float('inf')
        
        # Iterate through each vertex in the target mesh
        for target_vert_index, target_vert in enumerate(target_mesh.data.vertices):
            target_location = target_mesh.matrix_world @ target_vert.co
            
            # Calculate the distance between source and target vertices
            distance = (source_location - target_location).length
            
            # Check if the distance is within the specified radius
            if distance <= sphere_radius and distance < min_distance:
                min_distance = distance
                nearest_vert_index = target_vert_index
        
        # Store the nearest vertex index for the current source vertex
        #nearest_verts[source_vert_index] = nearest_vert_index
        
        # Check if the nearest vertex is found and print a message
        if nearest_vert_index is not None:
            print(f"Found nearest vertex for Vertex {source_vert_index} on {source_mesh.name}: {nearest_vert_index} on {target_mesh.name}. Distance: {min_distance}")
            
            # Move UV coordinates as soon as nearest vertex is found
            uv_layer_name = 'Lightmap'  # Update with the actual name of the UV layer
            model_a_uv = source_mesh.data.uv_layers[uv_layer_name].data
            model_b_uv = target_mesh.data.uv_layers[uv_layer_name].data
            
            model_a_uv[source_vert_index].uv = model_b_uv[nearest_vert_index].uv
            print(f"Moved UV coordinates from Model B :{model_b_uv[source_vert_index].uv} (Vertex {nearest_vert_index})to Model A: {model_a_uv[source_vert_index].uv} (Vertex {source_vert_index})")

    return nearest_verts

# Specify the names of Model A and Model B
model_a_name = "SK_Assassin_Top_MALE.001"  # Replace with the actual name of Model A
model_b_name = "Human_Male_TPV.001"  # Replace with the actual name of Model B

# Get the Blender objects corresponding to the specified names
model_a = bpy.data.objects.get(model_a_name)
model_b = bpy.data.objects.get(model_b_name)

# Set the sphere radius for the trace
sphere_radius = 1.0  # Adjust this value as needed

# Check if both specified objects are meshes
if model_a and model_b and model_a.type == 'MESH' and model_b.type == 'MESH':
    nearest_verts_dict = find_nearest_vertex(model_a, model_b, sphere_radius)
else:
    print("Please make sure both specified objects are valid mesh objects.")
```

This is the output (example not all) from the logs

```
Found nearest vertex for Vertex 5540 on SK_Assassin_Top_MALE.001: 2466 on Human_Male_TPV.001. Distance: 0.029112253009637285
Moved UV coordinates from Model B :<Vector (0.0284, 0.0127)> (Vertex 2466)to Model A: <Vector (0.4663, 0.3554)> (Vertex 5540)
Found nearest vertex for Vertex 5541 on SK_Assassin_Top_MALE.001: 3041 on Human_Male_TPV.001. Distance: 0.031595449994876755
Moved UV coordinates from Model B :<Vector (0.0259, 0.0134)> (Vertex 3041)to Model A: <Vector (0.3781, 0.4326)> (Vertex 5541)
Found nearest vertex for Vertex 5542 on SK_Assassin_Top_MALE.001: 2466 on Human_Male_TPV.001. Distance: 0.024464679265880036
Moved UV coordinates from Model B :<Vector (0.0284, 0.0127)> (Vertex 2466)to Model A: <Vector (0.4663, 0.3554)> (Vertex 5542)
```